# Configure httpd service timeout with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

## Intro

I have a worker environment setup with AWS Elastic Beantstalk. It is using the Apache proxy on a Linux 2 AMI.
My worker environment occasionaly has to handle longer running tasks (around 120s).

## Problem

I've noticed longer lasting tasks get resend to the SQS queue and thus are handled more then once.
I've already taken care of the `Visibility timeout` and `Inactivity timeout` so that this would not happen, but the issue persists.
After checking my logs at /var/log/httpd/access_log I noticed 504 errors on exaclty 60 seconds, telling me I somewhere hit another timeout.

## Hacky solution

I was able to solve it by increasing the httpd Timeout from 60s to 120s by manually changing the value in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and restarting the httpd service.

The issue still comes back each time autoscaling happens or the server is restarted. The value gets reset to 60 seconds.
What is needed is a way to set the timeout through configuration, bringing me to me actual question: How can i configure the httpd timeout setting with Elastic Beanstalk in a maintable way?

[This article](https://dev.to/rizasaputra/understanding-aws-elastic-beanstalk-worker-timeout-42hi) brought me so far, but the solution provided (using .ebextensions) seems to be for the deprecated Linux AMI (using linux 2).

## What I've tried

I've read op on configuring the proxy [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).
I've tried all the following configurations, but it appears the configuration isn't being picked up at all.

### Initial try:

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- .ebextensions
|   -- ....
|-- .platform
|   `-- httpd
|       `-- conf.d
|           `-- timeout.conf
`-- index.php
```

**.platform/httpd/conf.d/timeout.conf**

```
Timeout 120
```

### Added 00_reload.config

based of [this](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/issues/144).

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- .ebextensions
|   -- ....
|-- .platform
|   `-- httpd
|       `-- conf.d
|           `-- timeout.conf
|   `-- 00_reload.config
`-- index.php
```

**.platform/httpd/00_reload.config**

```
container_commands:
   01_reload_httpd:
     command: "service httpd reload"
```

### Overwrite the default apache config completely

if possible I would not like to do this as it becomes a maintenance nightmare.

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- .ebextensions
|   -- .....
|-- .platform
|   `-- httpd
|       `-- conf
|           `-- httpd.conf
`-- index.php
```

### .platform/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

It's a complete copy of the default provided by AWS, but changed the Timout setting to 120.

```
# Managed by Elastic Beanstalk
PidFile /run/httpd.pid

Listen 80
User apache
Group apache
LogLevel warn
TraceEnable off
EnableSendfile on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# Enable TCP keepalive
Timeout 120
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 60

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
.....
```

Answer (score 5):

It appears beanstalk assumes the `.platform` folder to be at the absolute root of your project. Mine was located inside my document root: `/public/.platform/`

The confusing started because the documentation showed it to be at the same level as the `.ebextensions` folder, which does need to be inside your document root (`/public` for me). There's also no mention about this anywhere.

Once I figured that out, the documentation of AWS was working perfectly. My final config below.

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- public
|   -- .ebextensions
|   -- index.php
|-- .platform
|   `-- httpd
|       `-- conf.d
|           `-- increase_timeout.conf
```

**.platform/httpd/conf.d/timeout.conf**

```
Timeout 120
```

I hope my struggles can be of help to someone down the line.

Comment: God bless you man. I've been struggling with this all day. The thing is, I had just upgraded a worker environment from Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2, and this issue did not exist on Amazon Linux 1.

Turns out that on the old environment we had httpd + mod_php. Now we have httpd (or nginx) + php-fpm. 

I don't know many of the inner workings of this new setup, but the requests are basically being proxied to php-fpm. Apache2 httpd has a `Timeout` and a `KeepAliveTimeout` setting which by default is `60` . Once I changed that, through the method you described, everything started working.

Comment: `.ebextensions` should be at project root